# ajax keep posting also previous requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, event-propagation

Working with Bootstrap framework 3.3.7
I have a code like this:

```
$('#field_submit').click(function() {
       //omitted part not relevant
       if (counter == 0) {
           //non ho riscontrato errori, quindi posso inviare il form
           data = $('#new_field').serialize();
           $.ajax({
           //omitted part not relevant
           }).done(function(data) {
            //aggiungo il campo creato alla lista dei campi sulla sinistra
            if(data.status==200){
                //omitted part not relevant
            }else{
              //non sono riuscito a caricare i dati
              $('#modal-text').html('<p class="text-danger">'+data.message+'</p><b>Dati per il debug</b> (saranno inviati in automatico nella mail):<br>');
              var risposta = data;
              $("#modal-text").append(JSON.stringify(data));
              $('#message').modal('show');
              $('.segnalazione').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr('id')=='error_submit'){
                  mail= true;
                }
                //effettuo il caricamento
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'segnalazione.php',
                  method: 'post',
                  data: {form:'new_field', valori:risposta, mail: mail},
                  dataType: 'json'
                });
              });
            }       
          });
       }
   });
```

As you can see if the main ajax call returns a status different from 200 then I open a modal, display some informations and on click of any of the two buttons (class="segnalazione") I send some data to the second ajax call.

Modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade fade" id="message" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Crea un nuovo campo</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-text">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary segnalazione" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary segnalazione" id="error_submit" data-dismiss="modal">Invia mail</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Consider this case: I open the page, run the first ajax, display the modal and send the data. This works fine. 
Then, **without reloading the page** I do it again, show again the modal and send the data. This time I see two requests, the first with the data from the previous call, the second with the correct data. 
If I do it again, I will see three calls, first with first data, second with second data and third with the correct one.
So, after three times in the second page in the db I will have three times the first data, two times the second and once the third.

I tried to use stopPropagation but it will prevent the modal to be closed on click of the button (usind data-dismiss method).

Comment: I suggest moving the whole `else` block in a new function and call it from there. That way you will not have the issue Dmitrij pointed out and your code will look better as well and easy to understand! Hope it helps.

Comment: @LearningEveryday this would just do some makeup but will not prevent my issue (that is not the one pointed out in the answer below).

Comment: Ah! See you if you can clear the data variable(or assign it to another variable and clear that) at the end of the call.

Comment: actually there is nothing in my code that make them persistent. They are overwritten each time the code is executed. So the poin is where this sort of cache is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not keeping reference to first "data" via your second "data" because you are using same variable name. By naming you second variable "data" you will change your first one.

Suggest calling it "json" or something else. This way you avoid name collision.

JS Object reference is tied to variable name, not to data inside. By updating 2nd variable - in reality you update first one.

More info here: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Comment: thanks for your advice but the issue is not between outer and inner ajax. It is that if I call again the outer ajax the inner one gets executed twice. Once with th actual data and once with the data from the previous execution.